# how can I get custom data group by enum property with JPQL or Criteria Api in spring data?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I have an enumeration to store Currencies :

```
public enum Currency {

    USD,EUR,GBP

}
```

And I have Sales entity that contain currency as a property:

```
public class Sales {

    private Long id;
    private Merchant merchant;
    private Customer customer;
    private double amount;
    private Currency currency;

}
```

sample table data for sales is like below :

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------+
| id | merchant_id | customer_id | amount | currency |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------+
|  1 |           2 |           3 |  125.0 | EUR      |
|  2 |           1 |           2 |  135.0 | USD      |
|  3 |           3 |           5 |  140.0 | GBP      |
|  4 |           2 |           8 |   25.0 | USD      |
|  5 |           4 |           8 |   95.0 | EUR      |
|  6 |           6 |           9 |   85.0 | EUR      |
|  7 |           5 |           6 |   90.0 | USD      |
|  8 |           1 |           1 |  225.0 | EUR      |
|  9 |           7 |           2 |  350.0 | GBP      |
|  . |           . |           . |      . | .        |
|  . |           . |           . |      . | .        |
|  . |           . |           . |      . | .        |
|  . |           . |           . |      . | .        |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------+
```

this is my custom data model

```
    public class CustomDataModel{

      private Integer count; //record count
      private double total; // its total amount for specified currency 
      private Currency currency; //  it also could be String, it is doesn't matter  

}
```

My query params: **merchant_id** and **customer_id**.

I want to get result as **`List<CustomDataModel>`**  for example :

```
[  
   {  
      "count":5,
      "total":674.00,
      "currency":"USD"
   },
   {  
      "count":3,
      "total":561.00,
      "currency":"EUR"
   },
   {  
      "count":4,
      "total":715.00,
      "currency":"GBP"
   }
]
```

is it possible to get result like this. If it is how can i do it?

Comment: I don't understand how is your output List<CustomDataModel> dependeno on query params: merchant_id and customer_id.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get `List<CustomDataModel>` group by Currency. If so, there is no need to depend on `merchant_id` or `customer_id`.

You can add below `@Query` method in your repository as below:

```
@Query("select new com.demo.spring.domain.CustomDataModel(count(s), sum(s.amount), s.currency) from Sales s group by s.currency")
List<CustomDataModel> getGroupByCurrency();
```

Just make sure to convert Integer to Long as in - `private Integer count;` to `private Long count;` in your `CustomDataModel` class and add below constructor to it:

```
  public CustomDataModel(Long count, double total, Currency currency) {
    super();
    this.count = count;
    this.total = total;
    this.currency = currency;
}
```

If you want to group by merchant and customer, you can update the above group by clause as `...group by s.currency, s.merchant, s.customer`